# java ConcurrentMap get in null

Tags: java, guava

I have this ConcurrentMap

```
 ConcurrentMap<String, Byte[]> companyLogo = new MapMaker()
                   .concurrencyLevel(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())
                   .weakKeys()
                   .initialCapacity(1000)
                   .expiration(24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                   .makeMap();
```

and this piece of code

```
companyLogo.put("cpr48124", ArrayUtils.toObject(resize (request, ((Byte[])request.getSession().getAttribute(COMPANY_LOGO_KEY+ imageId)))));
companyLogo.get("cpr48124");
```

But `companyLogo.get("cpr48124");` is null. How can it be possible ?

Comment: try to print out this:
ArrayUtils.toObject(resize (request, ((Byte[])request.getSession().getAttribute(COMPANY_LOGO_KEY+ imageId))))

Comment: I'm not familiar with `MapMaker` is, but I'd guess that `weakKeys` might be your problem.

Comment: Have you tried with another Byte[], I mean "ssssss".getBytes()... or something similar, just to test it?. It might be a problem of you session's attribute

Comment: @bradimus I remove weakKeys and it works. Please convert to answer

Comment: @bradimus Since `"cpr48124"` is a string literal, it will be interned and thus always reachable.  I'm surprised `weakKeys()` has an effect on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `MapMaker` is, but I'd guess that `weakKeys` might be your problem.

It is likely that the 'weakness' of your new entry is making it unavailable since there are no other references to it.